# Не загружается вторая страница товаров

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

В ходе работы с интернет-магазином Wordpress на плагине WooCommerce столкнулся с проблемой. Когда я нажимаю на фильтр по определенному свойству товара мне показывает 8 товаров и внизу переключение страниц. Первая страничка загружается на ура, а остальные не грузятся и хром выдает ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста кто знает, в чем может быть причина? Все изображено на скриншотах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю как добавить еще несколько.

Comment: Без кода говорить не о чем. Почитайте https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress